# I would like to implement a product detail page using a select box

Tags: javascript, html, select

When you select a product from the carousel, li containing the selected products is created at the bottom, and you would like to find the total price.

For example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO23s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D159w.png)

```html
 <div class="select">
          <div id="result"></div>
          <div class="day">
            <p class="a">production day</p>
            <select id="select1" onchange="menu1()">
              <option value="">Please select a day</option>
              <option value="monday" data-price="2">monday(+2)</option>
              <option value="tuesday" data-price="3">tuesday(+3)</option>
              <option value="wednesday" data-price="4">wednesday(+4)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="code">
            <p class="a">product name</p>
            <select id="select2" onchange="menu2()">
              <option value="">Please select feed type</option>
              <option value="beef" data-price="10">beef(+10)</option>
              <option value="chicken" data-price="20">chicken(+20)</option>
              <option value="salmon" data-price="30">salmon(+30)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <li>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
          <div id="price">Total: $0</div>
 </div>
```

```js
function menu2() {
  const x = document.getElementById("select1");
  const y = document.getElementById("select2");
  const disp = document.getElementById("result");
  disp.innerHTML = "dog food("+x.value+')['+y.value+"]"
};


sum = 0;

let x = document.getElementById("select1");
let select1 = x.Option[s.selectedIndex].value;
let y = document.getElementById("select2");
let select2 = y.Option[s.selectedIndex].value;

if (select1=monday) {
  sum += 2;
} else if (select1=tuesday) {
  sum += 3;
} else if(select1=wednesday) {
  sum += 4; 
};

if (select2=beef) {
  sum += 10;
  } else if (select2=chicken) {
    sum += 20;
  } else if(select2=salmon) {
    sum += 30;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10;) {
  innerHTML += '<li><li>'
}
```

When options in two select boxes are selected, the corresponding values ​​are displayed in the selected product list and the prices specified for each option must be added.
I'm getting stuck when trying to add the price for each value using an if statement.

Comment: don't hard code the summing, iterate over the list elements and find the sub tag with the price and sum these values (text) after converting to float

Comment: give the selected `li` elements a specific CSS class